# Alarm() can be used in multithreading like this?

Tags: c, alarm

I'm curious if I am able to do the following with the unistd c function `alarm(int signal)`

Having my main.... and for each thread hat is created to initializate a SIGALRM with the function, which should close my thread in case of activating. Is this possible? or 1 SIGALRM / main is legal only?

Comment: Which `alert()` are you talking about? [this one?](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alert) I'm not aware of an "alert" in [unistd.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html)

Comment: Maybe ["this one"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alarm.html)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296923/different-signal-handler-for-thread-and-process-is-it-possible - maybe it doesn't answer your whole question, but it has interesting information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each  thread  in  a  process  has an independent signal mask, which
>   indicates the set of signals that the thread is currently blocking.  A
>   thread can manipulate its signal mask using pthread_sigmask(3).  In a
>   traditional single-threaded application, sigprocmask(2) can be used to
>   manipulate the signal mask.

from man 7 signal.

The problem is that alarm works per process, not per thread, so if the sigmask of the threads is the same, you can't really know which one will receive the signal.

Comment: So if one was to block it in the other threads it would be received in the one left?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so first, the [`alarm()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alarm.html) is actually taking an *unsigned* int value which is the number of seconds before it expires. So your example `int signal` isn't the correct implementation of `alarm()`, just FYI.

As far as this goes:

`for each thread that is created to initialization a SIGALRM` 
The `SIGALRM` that is generated is done so for the **process** not per thread, so you will have to catch the alarm and have some internal strategy to know which thread you raised it for and handle that accordingly. Once you have your handler, you can raise the alarm over and over again, however keep in mind:

> Alarm requests are not stacked;

So you'll have to do this one at a time. It's still possible, but not totally stright forward as you were hoping.

For very rough example of what I'm talking about:

- you have a "manager" which keeps track of requests
- thread 1 tells the manager it needs to handle something in 10s
- the manager "records" this and calls set `alarm(10)`
- thread 2 tells the manager it needs to be woken up in 3 seconds
- the manager calls `alarm(0)` to kill the alarm, calls `alarm(3)` then notes that once that goes off it needs to call `alarm(7)` to finish thread 1's sleep time
- in your alarm handler you just call the manager and let it know an alarm went off and it will wake the appropriate thread (2) then reset the alarm for the next one.